# example of jupyter/docker start-notebook.sh command?

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using the datascience-notebook jupyter docker image.

I would like to install some additional programs before launching
the notebook. (Why: the R package nlme is not compiling, is not able to untar itself).

So I would like to do

1.

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 ...omitting.... jupyter/datascience-notebook bash
```

meaning launch the bash shell inside the container, install some things to debug the problem, then

2. start-notebook.sh   .... what goes here? .....

I.e. how to specify the port forwarding and other things needed to launch the notbook inside the container?  Just an example, I can possibly figure out the rest.

This is just for debug, so it is oke if the approach is a shack.

Answer (score -2):

ok, here is how to do it.

1. docker run ....   jupyterimage start.sh bash
2. apt install ...
3. jupyter-notebook

Comment: you can also do 3. jupyter lab

Comment: No, this is not how you do it.